# Chart.js - Right use of object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, chart.js

i'm using chart.js to make some kind of charts for my admin panel but i'm not understanding how to use my json array of objects for making the correct dataset. What Have i to put in data field of dataset?

Thanks in advance! Simone

Here's my code:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: api_statistiche, type: "GET",dataType: "json",
data: {type:"top_most_ingredients",n:15}} )
.done(function(json) {
    if (!json) {
        alert( "error 1" );
        return;
    }
    if (json.res!=1 || !json.data) {
        alert( "error 2" );
        return;
    }
    var max=json.data.length;
    var data=[];
    for (i=0;i<max;i++){
        el=json.data[i];
        data[i]={
            label: el.nome,
            value: el.n
            };

    }
    console.log(data); // Show 'data' correctly
var data = {
datasets: [{
    data: ?,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you!

**SOLVED:**

```
var data=[];
data['labels']=[];
data['datasets']=[];
data['datasets'][0]={
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: [],
    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    label: 'Like'
};
for (i=0;i<max;i++){
    el=json.data[i];
    data['labels'][i]=el.nome;
    data['datasets'][0].data[i]=el.n;
    data['datasets'][0].backgroundColor[i]=getRandomColor();
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("more_like_ingredients");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx,{type: 'polarArea',data: data});
```

Answer (score 4):

i think you need some object like this...

```
{label: aPalos[u],
  fillColor: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.05)",
  strokeColor: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.8)",
  pointColor: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.8)",
  pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
  pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
  pointHighlightStroke: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.8)",
  data: aPorcentajes[u]
}
```

here I leave my method if it's any help to understand it better

```
    _generarLineChart(){
  var datos = this.props.historial;
  var len = datos.length;

  var aNameS = [];
  var objHits = [];
  var dataL = {};
  var aPorcentajes = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ];
  for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(datos[i].selected){
      let nombre = datos[i].data.trainingSession.name;
      let field = datos[i].data.trainingSession.field;
      let round = datos[i].data.trainingSession.round;
      if(nombre){
        aNameS.push(nombre + ' - Round ' + round + ' ' + field);
      } else {
        aNameS.push(field);
      }

      let hits = datos[i].data.hits;
      for (var k=0;k<10;k++){
        let porcent;
        let hit = hits[k][1];
        if(hit == 0){
          porcent = 100;
        } else{
          porcent = parseInt((hits[k][0] / hits[k][1]) * 100);
        }
        aPorcentajes[k].push(porcent);
      }

    }
  }


  for (var u=0;u<10;u++){
    objHits.push({label: aPalos[u],
      fillColor: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.05)",
      strokeColor: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.8)",
      pointColor: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.8)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba("+aColoresGraph[u]+",0.8)",
      data: aPorcentajes[u]
    });
  }
  dataL['labels'] = aNameS;
  dataL['datasets'] = objHits;
  return dataL;
}
```

and here are the documentation for structure chartsjs
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-data-structure

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to do it but i receive this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". What's wrong?